# Git remote with multiple sub projects

Tags: git

I have a group of projects/modules that are related enough that i want them in the same repository but they live accross multiple directories locally on my machine. Is there a way I can add them as sub directories in a remote repository?

this is how i would normally add a remote

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@example.com:2227/usr/local/git_root/foo_project.git
```

would something like this work

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@example.com:2227/usr/local/git_root/foo_project.git/A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use submodules:

- Create a repository for each module/project
- Create a repository for the main project that will contain them
- Add the modules/projects to the main repository as submodules:
  `git submodule add ssh://git@example.com:2227/module1 module1/`

Answer (score 0):

You would do it the other way around. Git repositories are very cheap, so you usually create a new repository for each subproject if they are not directly dependent on each other. This also makes for a cleaner history as when one is working on project *A*, he does not get involved with all the changes that happened in project *B*.

So, you would maybe do it like this:

```
ssh://git@example.com:2227/usr/local/git_root/foo_project/a.git
ssh://git@example.com:2227/usr/local/git_root/foo_project/b.git
```

If you have one *“master”* project that should link them all, then submodules are a good choice. You would set up the master project and add a submodule for each subproject. That way you would have the complete project contained in the master project but would still be able to work independently on the subprojects.